# Проблема с часовыми поясами при работе с датой в javascript

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема с датами в разных браузерах.
Предположим, есть две даты, которые передаются в `JSON` в виде текста с сервера:

```
Array [ "2015-11-11T12:01:00", "2015-11-23T09:44:00" ]
```

Задача: для виджета, с помощью которого пользователь устанавливает время (используется `bootstrap-timepicker.js`), используется переменная типа `Date`. Необходимо вне зависимости от часового пояса заполнять эту дату с сервера, и так же отдавать обратно после изменения.

Для этого получаю с сервера дату в виде текста, создаю переменную `new Date("2015-11-11T12:01:00")`. Очевидно, что для `new Date` берется текущий часовой пояс пользователя. Т.к. я просто отбрасывал в итоге упоминание о часовом поясе, проблемы не было, использовалось только время. Однако в `Chromium` время дополнительно меняется в соответствии с часовым поясом. 
Chromium:

```
Wed Nov 11 2015 15:01:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
Было: 2015-11-11T12:01:00

Mon Nov 23 2015 12:44:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
Было: 2015-11-23T09:44:00
```

В Iceweasel такой проблемы нет:

```
"Wed Nov 11 2015 12:01:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)" 
Было: "2015-11-11T12:01:00" 

"Mon Nov 23 2015 09:44:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)" 
Было: "2015-11-23T09:44:00"
```

Если я разбиваю входную строку с датой-временем и пытаюсь сделать дату-время в UTC, результат тот же:

Получаю год, месяц, день

```
["2015", "11", "23"]
```

Час, минуты, секунды

```
["09", "44", "00"]

new Date(Date.UTC(year, month-1, day, hour, min))
```

в результате в Chromium дает:

```
Wed Nov 23 2015 12:44:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
```

В Iceweasel по-прежнему все ok:

```
Array [ "2015", "11", "23" ] 
Array [ "09", "44", "00" ] 
Date 2015-11-23T09:44:00.000Z
```

Comment: любая дата в яваскрипте хранится в UTC, а выводится в локальном

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, надо сделать поведение одинаковым в разных браузерах. Для этого надо добавить букву Z в конец строкового представления даты - тем самым явно указать браузеру что дата находится в UTC.

---

Получить дату и время в том же виде, в котором они были отправлены с сервера, можно при помощи UTC-функций:

```
var d = new Date("2015-11-11T12:01:00Z")
d.getUTCHours() // 12
d.toUTCString() // Wed, 11 Nov 2015 12:01:00 GMT
```

Если вам нужен объект Date, который бы давал такие же значение при вызове обычных методов - можно сделать так:

```
var d = new Date("2015-11-11T12:01:00Z")
d = new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds())
d.getHours() // 12
d.toString() // Wed Nov 11 2015 12:01:00 GMT+0500 (RTZ 4 (зима))
```

Этот способ пригодится в качестве костыля если используемая вами библиотека не имеет режима работы UTC.

---

Однако советую задуматься над задачей - нет ли проблемы в самой постановке? Обычно ситуация, когда сервер работает по UTC, а пользователю все даты показываются в местном времени - совершенно нормальная ситуация, так и должно быть.

PS Посмотрите в сторону библиотеки [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: выполнил Ваш первый код, в Chromium: `12` и 
`Wed, 11 Nov 2015 12:01:00 GMT`, в Iceweasel: `9` и `Wed, 11 Nov 2015 09:01:00 GMT`. Задача стоит - редактирование даты пользователем в UTC, без привязки к часовому поясу.

Comment: @Emm вынес важное замечание в начало

Comment: спасибо, именно эта буква помогла, теперь все работает одинаково в обоих браузерах

Answer (score 0):

Естественно UTC будет менять время. Метод `Date.UTC` полностью аналогичен конструктору Date с единственным отличием: полученное значение вычисляется по времени UTC, а не по локальному времени.

```
var dt = "2015-11-23T09:44:00",
    matches;

if(matches = dt.match(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})$/)) {
    var ndt = new Date(matches[1], matches[2]-1, matches[3], matches[4], matches[5]);
    console.log(ndt);
}
```

В консоли `Mon Nov 23 2015 09:44:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)`